# Trigger event when Bokeh DataTable Selection

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to trigger a callback event when I select a row (or rows) of a Bokeh `DataTable`?

```
def update(rows):
   ...

dt = DataTable(...)
dt.on_select(update)
```

I see that there is an `.on_change` method that can trigger on a particular property, however I can not find a property that corresponds to the selected rows.

Comment: See different solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746902/how-to-get-bokeh-datatable-cell-content-on-click/47886047#47886047

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that selecting a row of a data table is the same as making a selection on a data source. So, if you attach a callback to the datasource powering the table then the callback should work.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(mpg)
columns = [....]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns)
source.on_change('selected', callback)
```

Comment: Will this work in a notebook or does this require an active bokeh server?

Comment: This will work in a notebook/html with CustomJS callback.

`source.callback = CustomJS(code=.....)`

I'm not aware of server style callbacks working generally in notebooks.

Comment: How can you get the selected row data?

Comment: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource.data

source.data gives you the data dictionary from which you extract the relevant data.

Comment: Is this still working? attempted to add a callback on nonexistent DataTable.selected property

Comment: See the link in my Jan 13 comment. `DataTable` does not have a selected property. The `ColumnDataSource` does.

Answer (score 13):

The above answer by birdsarah is correct up to bokeh version 0.12.16 but as of bokeh version 0.13 you need to slighty change the on_change method to make it work:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(mpg)
columns = [....]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns)

def callback(attrname, old, new):
    selectionIndex=source.selected.indices[0]
    print("you have selected the row nr "+str(selectionIndex))
source.selected.on_change('indices', callback)
```